# How to launch ec2 instance with custom root volume ebs size (more than 8GB) using AWS Cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ebs

I'm trying to launch an ec2 instance using AWS CLI, but default root volume is 8GB only. how can I launch ec2 instance using CLI with say 100GB of root volume?

I'm trying this command,

```sh
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxxxx --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro \
--subnet-id xxxxxxx \
--key-name my-key \
--security-group-ids sg-xxxxxx \
--no-associate-public-ip-address \
--user-data file://test.sh \
--tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=test-server}]'
```

I tried adding below parameters, but its not working.

- `--block-device-mapping DeviceName=/dev/sda1,Ebs={VolumeSize=100}`
- `--block-device-mapping /dev/sda1=:100:false`
- `--block-device-mappings <value>` (adds secondary EBS volume to the instance).

Comment: Is there some error you are getting? Also, why are you trying to specify the volume size in two different ways?  This : `--block-device-mapping /dev/sda1=:100:false` is deprecated syntax, you should be fine with just using `--block-device-mapping DeviceName=/dev/sda1,Ebs={VolumeSize=100}`

Answer (score 14):

This is covered in the AWS CLI Documentation here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html

To launch an instance with a modified block device mapping

You can change individual characteristics of existing AMI block device mappings to suit your needs. Perhaps you want to use an existing AMI, but you want a larger root volume than the usual 8 GiB. Or, you would like to use a General Purpose (SSD) volume for an AMI that currently uses a Magnetic volume.

Use the describe-images command with the image ID of the AMI you want to use to find its existing block device mapping. You should see a block device mapping in the output:

```
{
  "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
  "Ebs": {
    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
    "SnapshotId": "snap-1234567890abcdef0",
    "VolumeSize": 8,
    "VolumeType": "standard",
    "Encrypted": false
  }
}
```

You can modify the above mapping by changing the individual parameters. For example, to launch an instance with a modified block device mapping, add the following parameter to your run-instances command to change the above mapping's volume size and type:

```
--block-device-mappings file://mapping.json
```

Where mapping.json contains the following:

```
[
  {
    "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
    "Ebs": {
      "DeleteOnTermination": true,
      "SnapshotId": "snap-1234567890abcdef0",
      "VolumeSize": 100,
      "VolumeType": "gp2"
    }
  }
]
```

To do this on one command line, the command should be in the format:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --block-device-mapping DeviceName=/dev/xvda,Ebs={VolumeSize=100} --image-id ami-0a5e707736615003c --region eu-west-1 --instance-type t3.micro
```

Note that the device name needs to match the root device name, which you can find with a command in the format:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --image-id ami-0a5e707736615003c --region eu-west-1
```